# White space at header in mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header

My website is https://salesportalasia-testsite.azurewebsites.net

When view using mobile there is white space at header.

I have check the margin-top code in css but not success.

Can someone please help me solve this problem...

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , then come back and edit your question. Please note that links referring to external sites will not be helpful for others in the future since the contents of that location is probably going to change.

Answer (score 1):

You have a inlined style `padding-top: 211px` on div with id="page". Remove it, and this white space will disappear.

Comment: Questions like this should imho not be rewarded with answers.

Comment: @connexo, Maybe you are right, but that took me just 1 minuet to check. If it take more, than probably, I wouldn't answer at all.

Comment: It's not a question of how long it takes, it's a question of not making OP, who ist a SO beginner, think that this is a proper way to ask questions here.

Comment: @connexo, okay, got it.

Answer (score 0):

Assign `padding-top:0px !important;` in mediaqueries

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
   .wrapper {
      padding-top:0px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions like this should imho not be rewarded with answers.

Comment: He is new to stackoverflow...He will post clearly in future

Comment: Exactly **because**, not despite of OP being new it is important to help him on the right path straight away. If he succeeds with this kind of question I guarantee the next question won't be of better quality either.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the page in mobile view, you will see that some inline styling is being applied to `<div id="page" style="padding-top: 160px"></div>`.

It looks like it is being set in `custom.min.js` in the `setNavigationOffset` function.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have padding-top:160px in top.

```
element.style {
    padding-top: 160px;
}
```

In the page it looks like hardcoded inside theme page,

[image]

Its possible you have different padding-top in different mobile devices so please check that and resolve it according the device. That will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css code for removing the padding top which results in  the white space.

```
#page{
padding-top:0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem you are facing due to multiple positioning of navigation element.

```
@media (max-device-width: 800px) and (orientation: portrait)
@media (max-width: 767px)
style.css?ver=4.7.5:7526
.navigation {
    position: relative!important;
}
```

This above class overwrite your fixed position class value.

```
.navigation-fixed-top .navigation {
top: 0;
position: fixed; /* This not work
bottom: inherit;
}
```

Here if you want to overcome. Just simply remove relative class

**TO REMOVE**

```
    @media (max-device-width: 800px) and (orientation: portrait)
@media (max-width: 767px)
style.css?ver=4.7.5:7526
.navigation {
    position: relative!important;
}
```

Otherwise if you want to use above class. Remove ! important keyword.
 Change like this.

```
    @media (max-device-width: 800px) and (orientation: portrait)
@media (max-width: 767px)
style.css?ver=4.7.5:7526
.navigation {
    position: relative;
}
```

So navigation element automatically get the fixed class value based on priority..

Hops it helps.!